# How to remove "read more" link from custom post type excerpt

Tags: custom-post-types, excerpt, read-more

Is there a way I can add some kind of `pre_get_posts()` filter to strip out the "read more" link that appears at the end of `the_excerpt()` for only 1 certain custom post type that I specify?

If so, can someone please help me out with the code? I've been working at it for a while but haven't gotten anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted a quick and easy solution, you could always just display:none the read_more link on that specific CPT

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that. But I'd prefer to strip the link out completely if possible so that Google does not follow and cache these specific pages.

Comment: The answer to this question is theme specific and not specific to WordPress as different themes include different code for adding the read more link http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Displaying_a_.22more.E2.80.A6.22_link_when_using_the_the_excerpt.28.29

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this by adding the below to functions.php

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Courtesy of [Remove more or [...] text from short post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162109/remove-more-or-text-from-short-post)

Answer (score 6):

Put the following code in `functions.php` to show "read more" on all post types except `custom_post_type`.

```
function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
  global $post;
  if ($post->post_type != 'custom_post_type')
  {
    $output .= '<p><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">read more</a></p>';  
  }
  return $output;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to put following code inside `style.css`:

```
 a.read-more {
    display:none;
 }
```

This targets `<a class="read-more">`

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer, because the method doesn't provide a parameter to override it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Basically it's a way to customize the text by adding a callback function to the functions.php file. I'm thinking, however, if you just return a space instead, then it *should* override it and not display anything.

```
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return ' ';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

I got this from [The Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Displaying_a_.22more.E2.80.A6.22_link_when_using_the_the_excerpt.28.29)

Edit:

This is untested, but what if you do this:

```
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   if ($post->post_type == 'your-cpt')
   {
      return "&nbsp;";
   }
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

To reiterate, I haven't tested this, but may get you on the right track (i.e. var_dump($post) to see how you can bend it to your will from within the new_excerpt_more function.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but pasting that exact code into my functions.php file actually breaks the entire site. Also, I'll need the function to grab only the posts from the 'staff-members' custom post type.

Comment: Thanks for the help! There's still some kind of error in the syntax there that takes down the whole site and loads a blank page. I will see if I can figure it out. Your logic on this seems sound.

Comment: You need to return `$more` end of the function otherwise all other post type will miss the more tag/text.

Answer (score -1):

```
function custom_theme_developement_view_product_button(){
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo '<a href="" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="View cart"></a>'; 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_theme_developement_view_product_button', 11 );
```