# Remove more or [...] text from short post

Tags: excerpt, limit

I use a theme that have a character limit for shortpost and show [...] at the end of character limit.

I want to remove this, so I search for `the_excerpt();` and replace with `the_content();`

The problem solve with normal content but still have problem with image post type and there is `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` that when I change this my shortpost act like full post and it's not related to the length of post.

I try to open all PHP files in theme and looking for key words like: limit, length, excerpt for find where is the code that define the length of shortpost even search for "[...]" in all files and language but I don't know where is that come from.

But all I find is some line of code in `function.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'string_limit_words' ) ) :
function string_limit_words($str, $limit = 18 , $need_end = false) {
    $words = explode(' ', $str, ($limit + 1));
    if(count($words) > $limit) {
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words,'...');
    }
    return implode(' ', $words);
}
endif;
```

And when I increase 18 nothing change!

What code I must looking for?

Answer (score 28):

The codex is your friend and should be your first stop :-)

The `[...]` is added by [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#For_versions_2.9_and_higher_of_WordPress). There is a filter supplied called the [`excerpt_more`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) filter that is specifically included to customize the read more text after the excerpt

To remove the `[...]` after the excerpt text, you can do the following

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: thanks for reply 

your code is work well for remove [...] , but still the shortpost are limited and word cut after some characters 

I want act normal ( everything before read more tag show on my short post )

Comment: another Question just for curious , how can i change the [...] to some thing else for example [ more ... ]

Comment: You should read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545). I've covered about everything in that post. Hope it helps :-). Remeber to accept my answer if it helped solving your issue.

Comment: this seems to only remove the read more link. The `[...]` is still there.

Comment: Great, this is working also for Query loop excerpt block in Gutenberg editor.

Answer (score 6):

As others have already pointed out, using the `excerpt_more` filter hook is the right way to go.

Just wanted to add that you don't have to write a function that returns an empty string. WordPress has a few built in functions to return true, false, zero, null, empty string or empty array.

In this case we need [__return_empty_string()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string)

You can add this code to your plugin or to your theme's functions.php:

```
<?php 
// This will add a filter on `excerpt_more` that returns an empty string.
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', '__return_empty_string' ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your `functions.php`

```
    function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';//you can change this to whatever you want
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Also, using `the_excerpt` has the advantage that automatically cleans the content, and deletes all images, and other HTML tags.

You can [read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more)

If you also want to modify the length of the excerpt, you can add this snippet to your `functions.php`:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;//change the number for the length you want
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

You can read more about this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length)

Comment: Which versions are you targeting, that is pre 2.9 :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I guess the wrong one.

Comment: your code work well with changing length but when i remove [...] it will be ugly when a part of paragraph looks missing 

it will be great if somehow detect a paragraph instead lenght !!

// another problem with excerpt is about shortcodes , i cant put video player or slideshow to my short post

Comment: @Arioman, you can change the [...] with a link that says "Keep reading", or whatever you want. Now, if you want to have working shortcodes, `the_excerpt` isn't what you are looking for, you should add that to the question, as the answers will change.

Comment: @TomásCot thanks for this fantastic guide . i put all codes (complete code) in my function.php and remove $wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); for accept all tags i use stream video player for insert video and it generates shortcodes like : [stream flv=http://****/clip/shad.m4v embed=false share=false width=640 height=360 dock=true controlbar=over bandwidth=high autostart=false responsive=16:9 /] but still i get a text : *Video: my video instead of showing my video player in shortpost where is my problem ??

Comment: Can you add the cod eto the question?

Answer (score 1):

that is work for me !

```
function change_excerpt( $text )
{
    $pos = strrpos( $text, '[');
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        return $text;
    }

    return rtrim (substr($text, 0, $pos) );
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'change_excerpt');
```

Answer (score 1):

'excerpt_more' is a WordPress hook. It returns the content excerpt.
To remove the [...] after the excerpt text, you can return blank like below or your custom requirements. Use this code on function.php

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new function in your `functions.php`:

```
function custom_excerpt() {
 $text=preg_replace( "/\\[&hellip;\\]/",'place here whatever you want to replace',get_the_excerpt());
echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
}
```

Then use the new function on your page.